# Make div go to the bottom without overlapping previous div's content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following example:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/yLty3552/2/

Pen: http://codepen.io/yisera/pen/KpzbQp

Where I have a flex grid and I have elements that are also `display:flex;`. The problem I have is that the `div.card` has another div, `div.od-card-action` which has the actions of that card, comment, upvote, downvote. However, whenever the content of one of the cards is bigger than the others, they will stretch, making the card bigger to match the biggest one on that row.

This is a desired behaviour, but the problem is the `div.od-card-action` will also grow (I don't want this to happen) and make the elements seem out of order like it is shown on the first card in the fiddle.

I tried:

```
.od-card-action{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

but this only makes the content from the upper div overlap with the content of the actions div.

Is there a way where I can make the `div.od-card-action` go all the way to the bottom regardless of the size of the card and maintain the same size (eg: 50px to say a value)?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's a picture demonstration what I want to accomplish:
[image]

See how everything is aligned horizontally despite the content of the above div not being of the same size? That's what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the od-card-action CSS back to:

```
.od-card-action{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Add new css to card-content

```
.card-content{
   margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: looking at your fiddle now.

Comment: There's a link to a fiddle on the first line. But let me make a pen then.

Comment: Sorry, I cant even recreate the issue :/

Comment: So sorry, i completely misunderstood what you were looking for. I've updated my answer. See if that works for you. :)

Comment: check it on the pen and on the fiddle.. That's what I'm trying to avoid, that the div with the comment/upvote/downvote section doesn't get messed like that - one taller than the other due to the previous div content.

Comment: so you want all the "comment/upvote/downvote section"'s to be aligned horizontally? Sorry, I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: I need the to be the same size and aligned horizontally, yes. Something like this, adding an image to my post to show you how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77853/discussion-between-ally-ripp-and-codeninja).

Comment: Updated my answer again. if this isn't what you are looking for, please contact me in chat :)

Comment: Just contacted you via chat.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that as you're already using Flexbox in `.od-card`, then `.card-content` could be set to take as much space as possible (vertically, as the flex direction is `column`) using:

```
.card-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```